# SQL Rank based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, sql-rank

I have a requirement to give rank based on the column value in table

Condition:

- prioritize JobType in the order of 1: 75, 2: 76, 3: 80 , 4: 64
- When there are two contacts with same JobType, prioritize RANK with
  OrderCount Desc
- Table also has other JobTypes that are not listed
- If there are other JobTypes, they should follow after matching the
  above condition
- If the customer doesn't have any matching JobTypes: 75, 76, 80 , 64
  The rank should be on the basis of OrderCount
- JobType is associated with ContactPerson

---

Case 1:
[case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a2SU.jpg)
Case 2:
[case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqVkD.jpg)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting pictures instead of code, but anyway, using `row_number()`, `rank()`, or `dense_rank()` along with a `CASE` expression should do it.

Not really following all your logic but something like:

```
select a.*
    , row_number() over (
        order by case
        when job_type = '1:75' then 1,
        when job_type = '2:76' then 2,
        when job_type = '3:80' then 3,
        when job_type = '4:64' then 4,
        else 5 end case,
        orderCount desc
    ) as rnk
from mytable
```

Comment: This is working only for 1 customer, but if I have multiple customers this code snip is not working

Comment: thanks for the idea, I have worked on some query and it is working for most the customers

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, row_number() over 
(partition by Market,Customer order by case
 when JobType = '75' then 1
 when JobType = '76' then 2
 when JobType = '80' then 3
 when JobType = '64' then 4
else 5 end , orderCount desc) as rnk
from mytable a
```

above query worked for me and I am testing it.